# Merge contents from three dataframes into one column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following three `data.frame`s.

```
 df1 <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
      c("text1", "texta", "textk", "textx"))
 names(df1) <- c('dummy_1', 'dummy_2')
 df2 <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
      c("text2", "textb", "textl", "texty"))
 names(df2) <- c('dummy_1', 'dummy_3')
 df3 <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
      c("text3", "textc", "textm", "textz"))
 names(df3) <- c('dummy_1', 'dummy_4')
```

How can I merge the text from the columns `dummy_2`, `dummy_3` and `dummy_4` in `df1`, `df2` and `df3`, respectively, into one column, separated by `" \n "`? So the desired outcome is this data.frame:

```
 dummy_1    merged
 A          text1 \n text2 \n text3
 B          texta \n textb \n textc
 C          textk \n textl \n textm
 D          textx \n texty \n textz
```

Comment: sentiment is appreciated, but you don't need to say "thank you" for each answer in comments; an upvote is considered sufficient ...

Comment: Ok, well, for the last time then: thank you (and another upvote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  reduce(left_join) %>%
  unite(merged, -dummy_1, sep = " \n ")
```

Output:

```
  dummy_1                  merged
1       A text1 \n text2 \n text3
2       B texta \n textb \n textc
3       C textk \n textl \n textm
4       D textx \n texty \n textz
```

Answer (score 2):

With `merge`:

```
step1 <- merge(merge(df1, df2, by='dummy_1'), df3, by='dummy_1')
result <- transform(step1, merged=paste(dummy_2, dummy_3, dummy_4, sep='\n'))
```

On a side-note, you don't have to add `names` afterwards:

```
df1 <- data.frame(dummy_1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
  dummy_2 = c("text1", "texta", "textk", "textx"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine all three data frames (you could use `cbind()` or `$`-referencing, but merging is safer in case `dummy_1` lists values in different orders):

```
df4 <- Reduce(merge, list(df1,df2,df3))
```

(in production code you might want to specify `by` explicitly as in @MrGumble's answer, but annoyingly `Reduce()` doesn't take a `...` argument so you need to define an anonymous function)

`paste()` the values together with a separator of `" \n "` (`transform()` is cosmetic, and possibly not recommended in production code):

```
df4 <- transform(df4,merged=paste(dummy_2,dummy_3,dummy_4,sep=" \n "))
```

Keep only the desired columns:

```
df4 <- df4[c("dummy_1","merged")]
```

Comment: Another great answer. Thank you so much, Ben.

Answer (score 2):

```
pasted <- paste(df1$dummy_2, df2$dummy_3, df3$dummy_4, sep = " \n ")

df_pasted <- data.frame(dummy_1 = df1$dummy_1, merged = pasted)
```

Comment: this is marginally unsafe because it relies on the orders being the same - `merge` or `left_join` are slightly better.  But this does solve the OP's problem as written.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Your answer is safe. My answer is case specific, but the order could be any, so merging is the best option